# adding action to select (combobox) in emberJs

Tags: ember.js, combobox, html-select

I am trying to add events for two values in the combobox using emberJs. This is what I have tried.

```
 <select class="bs-select form-control input-small">
        <option {{action 'allData' }}>All Data </option>
        <option {{action 'myData' }}>My Data </option>
      </select>
```

I have added two functions in my controller by name `allData` & `myData` but these functions never gets called. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a binding instead. {{view Ember.Select}}

see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

You can add a binding for the value and add an observer in your controller to do something when the señection changes.

Comment: Since Ember.js 2.0 Ember.Select is deprecated.
Here is the new way to do it : http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select